# Can't get all options in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all option available in a select, this is the html structure:

```
<select id='selected-service' size='5'>
  <option value='13'>Hair</option>
  <option value='14'>Color</option>
</select>
```

**code:**

```
var available_services = $('#selected-service').find('option:selected', this).map(function ()
{
         return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(available_services);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q4mdpf58/2/)

But I get an empty array, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well nothing is selected and the selector is wrong.

Comment: `.find` does not have an overload that takes 2 parameters. Your code will still work, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: What's wrong with `$('#selected-service').val()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to find only selected values, and you don't have any selected by default.

```
var available_services = $('#selected-service').find('option').map(function ()
{
     return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(available_services);
```

This will get you all options.

If you need to do this in an event, then go ahead and capture the event.

```
$('#selected-service').on('change', function(){
    var available_services = $(this).find("option:selected", this).map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(available_services);
});
```

Comment: another option instead of `find` and `map` is `available_services=$('option:selected',this).attr('value');`

Comment: @depperm I don't dispute that fact at all. Thank you for providing that alternative.

Comment: Use `.trigger('change')` on event handler to get the options list on page load

Answer (score 1):

`:selected` looks for selected options. Find, does not have a second argument.

```
var available_services = $('#selected-service').find('option').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(available_services);
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/q4mdpf58/5/

Comment: AS a sidenote, use `children` selector as `option` is always direct child of `select` or `$('select option')`

Answer (score 1):

while you need to loop through selected option in select .. you should add multiple attribute to select

```
<select id='selected-service' size='5' multiple>
```

and in js you can use **.each();**

```
var available_services = []
$('#selected-service > option:selected').each(function ()
{
         available_services.push($(this).attr('value'));
});

console.log(available_services);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/q4mdpf58/4/)

Comment: _"I'm trying to get all option available in a select"_ not selected options, also the var name `available_services` indicates the same.

Comment: @Tushar Its depending on what he meant with available .. as we can see in his code he used :selected  so maybe he need something for added it .. that's why I rely on that in my answer .. I know available mean get all values of options in select